# Parameter passing in Corba and RMI

Tags: java, rmi, corba

I am still learning the concept of remote invocation and have tried searching this up but I can't find any information that is explaining it in a way I can understand. I am trying to figure out what is passed by value and what is passed by reference in RMI and Corba. I have this question in the context of an example. I have one example that uses the out parameter in the IDL interface:
Client.java

```
PersonHolder person = new PersonHolder(p);//where p is a person with 2 values assigned "name" and "email"(this Person object was created in the client and was defined as a struct in the IDL)
    o.getPerson(person);
```

The getPerson was defined in the IDL as

```
         void getPerson(out Person p);
```

The server calls  the getPerson and attempts to print out the original values first. However when it prints on the server the values are all null. This looks as if the person the client passed in the PersonHolder was not passed at all.

I then tried this same example with inout type and the Person that the client passed in the PersonHolder did contain the data that was initialized by the client.

If anyone can explain to me the difference between in, out and inout in the context of this particular problem, it would be appreciated.

I hope this will give me a better understanding of parameter passing and return values in an RMI or Corba enviroment.

Comment: Objects in RMI and RMI/IIOP and Corba are passed by value unless they are remote objects themselves, in which case they are passed by remote reference.

Comment: @user207421 I do understand that. What i am not understanding is how the "out" idl type in corba sends an object from client to server where the server cannot read the clients object data at all nor write to it. All throw null pointer exceptions. While the inout "idl" type i can do both and it will have an automatic impact on the object created in the client. I am basically trying to figure out how in, out and inout work in the context of this problem to help me better understand.

Comment: The server can't read a client's `out` object because it hasn't been sent, but it can certainly assign it to a new object of the correct type and write to it and have it sent back in the response.